# Open SSRS report from asp.net and pass in CustID parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005, reporting-services

I need to link to a server side SSRS report from ASP.NET and pass in a CustID parameter.

Here is the link to the report

```
http://svr-ssrs/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fCOMPANY%2fMedical+Professional+Portfolio+Status+Report
```

I have tried adding &CustID=12345 to the end of the link, but that doesn't work.  How can I get the link to work and pass in the parameter?

We are using asp.net 3.5 and sql server 2005

Comment: Adding the parameter as you have should work according to here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa237802.aspx Are you sure `CustID` is the correct parameter name?

Comment: yes I checked the parameter page of the report in ssrs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your URL is wrong for direct access to the report with parameters. It should be `http://exampleWebServerName/reportserver?/foldercontainingreports/reportname`

If you append parameters onto this, it should work.

Taken from the same MSDN link as George posted.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work

http://svr-ssrs/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/COMPANY/Medical+Professional+Portfolio+Status+Report&CustID=12345

Answer (score 0):

- Open **reporting services configuration manager**
- Click on **Web Service URL**, locate **URLs:** copy the link and paste it your browser. navigate to folder:
- http://ServerName/ReportServer
- The report
- http://ServerName/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fFoldername%2freportname&rs:Command=Render&ParameterName=#value#
- [image]

[image]